# Access Stream Buffer HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, streaming

I'm trying to stream radio in a Windows Phone 7 app and for this I'm using `ManagedMediaHelpers`. The `HttpWebRequest` to get the continuous stream works but doesn't call the callback Url because of the continuous stream.

How do I access the stream without the help of the callback Url? On other posts some said O need to use reflection but does someone knows hot to implement it? Here is my code:

```
req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(
    "http://streamer-dtc-aa01.somafm.com:80/stream/1018");

// if this is false it will fire up the callback Url 
// but the mediastreamsource will throw an exception 
// saying the it needs to be true
req.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true; 

IAsyncResult result = req.BeginGetResponse(RequestComplete,null);

private void RequestComplete(IAsyncResult r)
{
    HttpWebResponse resp = req.EndGetResponse(r) as HttpWebResponse;
    Stream str = resp.GetResponseStream();

    mss = new Mp3MediaStreamSource(str, resp.ContentLength);
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
        this.me.Volume = 100;
        this.me.SetSource(mss);
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the ContentLength of a live radio stream?

Comment: Agreed! From debug i saw the value was -1...so any ideas or tips? Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue, so here is how I solved it:

[Getting bytes from continuous streams on Windows Phone 7](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/getting-bytes-continuous)

It might also be a problem with your URL - make sure that if you run the request outside the application, you are getting the necessary amount of data.

Comment: I'm doing pretty much the same in AudioStreamer agent and after some time stream.Read freezes forever. Did you face this kind of issues?

Comment: I have not. Feel free to open another questions that covers the issue.

Comment: I will, but for now I'm not sure why it's not working - is it a mem issue (it isn't), GC (it isn't) or HttpWebRequest specifics (donno).
Thank you for answering, Den